# Using regex on a file to pull data out. Having issues with multi-line

Tags: regex, ruby

I am looking to get to the next line of data within a text file. Here is an example of data from the file I am working with.

```
0519 ABF   244  AN        A1  ADV STUFF    1.0  2.0 Somestuff 018 0155  MTWTh      10:30A 11:30A    20     20     0  6.7                                                           
Somestuff 011 0145  MTWTh      12:30P  1:30P
```

I have been trying to move to the next line by utilizing a variety of code such as.. carriage return \n using \s+ to replace the large space after 6.7. using m like so //m  not finding a result just yet.

Here is some example code

```
while !regex_file.eof?
line = regex_file.gets.chomp
if line =~ ^.*?\d{4}\s+[A-Z]+\s+\d{3}.+$
puts line
  end
end
```

Using https://rubular.com/ this particular set of code matches my desired output for the first line

```
0519 ABF   244  AN        A1  ADV STUFF    1.0  2.0 Somestuff 018 0155  MTWTh      10:30A 11:30A    20     20     0  6.7
```

but does not match and haven't figured out how to match the next line.

```
Somestuff 011 0145  MTWTh      12:30P  1:30P
```

Comment: Your criterion for matching the first line is reflected in your regex. What is your criterion for matching the second line? For example, must it start with letters, then spaces then digits, then spaces, then more digits, or must it end with two times separated by a space, or something else? Please edit to explain your matching criterion for the second line

Answer (score 1):

Your current regex:

```
^.*?\d{4}\s+[A-Z]+\s+\d{3}.+$
```

matches in this order:

- the  beginning of the line (`^`)
- zero or more characters non-greedy `.*?`
- four digits (`\d{4}`)
- one or more spaces (`\s+`)
- one or more capital letters (`[A-Z]+`)
- one or more spaces
- **three digits** (`\d{3}`)
- one or more characters (`.+`)
- the end of the line (`$`)

The second line of your file is:

```
Somestuff 011 0145  MTWTh      12:30P  1:30P
```

starts matching `0145  MTWT` but then fails to match `\d{3}`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: the `\n` captures the new line, and you can apply your own rules to capture anything you want which comes after `\n` - see below pls:

```
^.*\d{4}\s+[A-Z]+\s+\d{3}.+\n.*$
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made an arbitrary assumption about the requirements for matching the second line. It is more demanding than the requirements for matching the first that are reflected in your regex, but I thought the additional complexity would have some educational value for you.

Here is a regular expression (untested) for matching both lines. Note you don't need `^.*?` at the beginning of the regex and for the part of the regex that matches the first line `.+$` adds nothing, so I removed it. After all you are just matching each line separately (`line`), and will display the entire line if there's a match. As well, the end-of-string anchor `\z` is more appropriate than the end-of-line anchor (`$`), though either can be used.

```
r = /
    (?:             # begin non-capture group   
      \d{4}         # match 4 digits
      \s+           # match > 0 whitespaces
      [A-Z]+        # match > 0 uppercase letters
      \s+           # match > 0 whitespaces
      \d{3}         # match 3 digits
    |               # or
      \b            # match a (zero-width) word break
      [A-Z]         # match 1 uppercase letter
      [a-z]*        # match >= 0 lowercase letter
      \s+           # match > 0 whitespaces
      \d{3}         # match 3 digits
      \s+           # match > 0 whitespaces
      \d{4}         # match 4 digits
      \s+           # match > 0 whitespaces
      [A-Za-z]+     # match > 0 letters
      (?:           # begin non-capture group
        \s+         # match > 0 whitespaces
        (?:         # begin a non-capture group
          0\d       # match 0 followed by any digit
        |           # or
          1[012]    # match 1 followed by 0, 1 or 2
        )           # end non-capture group
        :           # match a colon
        [0-5][0-9]  # match 0-5 followed by 0-9     
      ){2}          # end non-capture group and execute twice
    )               # end non-capture group  
    /x              # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

This regular expression is conventionally written as follows.

```
r = /(?:\d{4}\s+[A-Z]+\s+\d{3}|\b[A-Z][a-z]*\s+\d{3}\s+\d{4}\s+[A-Za-z]+(?:\s+(?:0\d|1[012]):[0-5][0-9]){2})/
```

You might go through the file `puts`ing matching lines as follows:

```
File.foreach(fname) { |line| puts line if line.match? r }
```

See [IO::foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-foreach), which is a very convenient method for reading files line-by-line. Note `IO` class methods (such `foreach`) are commonly invoked with `File` as their receiver. That's OK, as `File.superclass #=> IO`, so `File` inherits those methods from `IO`.

When used without a block `foreach` returns an enumerator, which is often convenient as well. If, for example, you wished to return an array of matching lines (rather than `puts` them), you could write:

```
File.foreach(fname).with_object([]) do |line, arr|
  arr << line.chomp if line.match? r
end
```